# Unity3d Transform.position float range

Tags: unity, floating-point

I thought floating point has a very large range, for example [up to 3.4*10^38](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
However today I tried to set my player's Transform.position.x to 1000000 in the GUI and it gave me a warning:

> "Due to floating-point precision limitations, it is recommended to bring the world coordinates of the GameObject within a smaller range."

Does that mean that my single scene has to be smaller than 1000000*1000000*1000000. Is this considered big enough? I will need multiple scenes if I want a larger world? When a new scene gets loaded, will my player's position be reseted? How do I manage the position data so that it doesn't go out of range?

I'm using Unity3D Pro.

Answer (score 4):

Floating point precision is all relative. The further away from the origin, the less absolute precision you have.

In unity's case, general best practices are to use 1 unit = 1 meter. Do you need your entities to be a million meters away from each other?

A common practice for games with huge worl'ds is to occasionally reset the player's and worlds position to the origin.

As for your other questions it really depends. We can't answer "is it big enough".

Have you tried making a prototype to scale and run into specific issues or are you just trying to make the error go away?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Question 1: why the further from the origin, the less absolute precision? Accumulated error?

Comment: Question 2: why 1 unit = 1 meter. Previously I thought you can scale everything in the game world as you like. Am I missing something here?

Comment: My player certainly don't need to see entities a million meters away, but my game world is an open space galaxy, so I want to know the upper space limit of my game world. That's why I'm trying out in Unity now.

Comment: Question 3: the "occasionally reset player's and world's position" part is probably what I should do. But I am doing a multiplayer online game. In this case I guess I'll need two coordinate systems? Otherwise the same game objects will have different positions at different players?

Comment: 1 unit : 1 meter is the assumption that the physics calculations are based on (e.g. acceleration due to gravity). You can tweak some of these constants in Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics